# double integration in matlab when one limit is a function of another integration variable

Tags: matlab, optimization, numerical-integration, rate

i was working on computing rate pairs of a 2 user communication channel.We use Lagrangian methods to get the optimum rate value for each user.
For this purpose we had to find the Lagrangian multipliers for an equation and solve for the rate equation.Both the equations have double integral and one of the limits is a function of another integrand variable.I wanted some help regarding using double integral in matlab.Also is it better to use int2 or dblquad?

Comment: what is int2? (I cannot find it on the matlab help)

Comment: int2 is integral2 used for double integrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html).

[`dblquad`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dblquad.html) is deprecated and doesn't even have the option of the integration limits being functions so your choice is easy. I recommend reading through the documentation for `integral2` and trying the examples. There's [one example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html#btdgcqw) where one of the upper limits is defined using an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Comment: but integral2 is not available in my 2010 version of matlab